# MNIST dataset with Bayesian Network python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have a research about soccer result prediction using bayesian network. But, I just a beginner on it. Then I want to start study about BN (Bayesian Network) with MNIST dataset, because my soccer dataset is just similar with MNIST, or I can say my dataset imitate the MNIST. I follow tutorial from this website https://alpha-i.co/blog/MNIST-for-ML-beginners-The-Bayesian-Way.html and I try it. But I can't get the result because there is out of memory output. I train the model from tutorial in CPU with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz, NVIDIA graphic with OpenGL renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2, and RAM 32.132,6 MB. Actually, I don't quite understand with the tutorial. I had tried ANN (Artificial Neural Network) using tensorflow with 500 data before I tried the BN and I got the result of ANN. But, why I can't get the BN result? Does BN need more memory space to run? Can I get other BN tutorials with MNIST??

Comment: I have to ask: How can your soccer data possibly be similar to MNIST??

Comment: The mnist dataset contains pixels data and with label, like 0, 1, 2, etc. Firtsly, I have match dataset from kaggle. Then I process the macth dataset so it contains list of id of home players, id of away players, and then label of win or lose for home team. Then, I change the id of all player become all skill indexex (like join in dataset). So finally, the dataset contains all of skill indexes of home player, skill indexes of away player, and win label (1 or 0) for home team. I think the dataset will be similar with MNIST.

Comment: Your dataset is not similar with MNIST at all, you have provided the right evidence for that claim.